# Python: Correct way to write to another directory within a package

Tags: python, package, abstraction

Currently working with the following package structure:

```
/package
    __init__.py
    final.py
    /write
        __init__.py
        write.py
    /data
        backup.txt
        backup1.txt
        backup2.txt
```

final.py imports write.py, which should be able to go back one directory and write a series of backup .txt files to /data.

final.py should be able to go into /data during **another call** and access the backup files, hence the need to save the information in /data.

1. I'm not sure this should be the correct hierarchy for a package file? How would /write create text files in a directory branch separate from itself without using absolute file paths in case the whole project file is moved, say onto a server.
2. Would it be wrong (once the backup.txt files are created) to add a retrieve.py to /data which returns the .txt files in some sort of data structure and make /data a package, or (2) should final.py directly enter /data and retrieve the text files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. IMO you shouldn't be writing into your packages. Set your code up so that you are writing to a data directory that is potentially outside your package. Numerous code deployment strategies assume that your code will be in a directory that is not normally writable. (E.g. if it is packaged for common linux distributions, the code will go into /usr/lib/python.../yourpackage/ and the data will be written to /var/lib/yourpackage, or something similar.)
2. Put your retrieve.py outside of .../data, possibly in a .../read directory, or alongside final.py, depending on the organization you need.

To write to an arbitrary location, just pass the full path to `open`. For example, assume that you store the path to your data directory in a constant:

```
DATA_PATH = '/var/lib/mypackage'

def backup():
    f = open(os.path.join(DATA_PATH, 'backup.txt'), 'w')
    f.write('some backup data...')
    f.close()
```

Comment: Even Windows developers have started doing that, what with Microsoft finally encouraging the separation of data files and program files starting with Windows Vista.

Comment: If I write to an outside directory, it will still present the problem of having write.py writing to a directory that is outside of itself. I'm not sure how I can easily go back and write the text files in another directory?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but I was wondering about pointing to another directory without specifying a full file path (so that i can move a whole directory (including final.py) else where if needed, hence why I changed designated the whole thing as a package)
Also it seems like I'm confused regarding the purpose of a package in Python. I've been using Python packages as simply a means of abstraction and organization, but it seems like this is not the main use? Would it be more practical to just throw everything in one layer (as this isn't project is heading more so to the web then a system)

Comment: @supernoobie: If you're targeting the web, it's even more important to be able to write your backups somewhere different from your code. A sane web deployment will put the code into a directory that's not writable by the webserver user. As I hinted at in the answer with the `DATA_PATH` variable, you should design your code so that the backups can be written to any arbitrary location -- you do not want to depend on having them at some path that is relative to your package.